# mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged() does not work in some cases

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview

I'm trying to update my `RecyclerView` by using `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()`. While it works when I use a button to update the list and gets reflected in the view but, it does not work when I call it from some other function which is **mqttcall function** named `messageArrived()`.

I tried re-initializing the whole list and adapter but still it does not work when called from `messageArrived()` function when works when I do it from button click.

```
fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            somefun();

        }
    });

public void somefun(){
    Pump pump = new Pump("71xxxxxx", "East Motor", "OFF",R.drawable.motor);

    pumpList.add(pump);
    mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}

public void messageArrived(String topic, MqttMessage message) throws Exception {
            Log.d("In main Activity","Message arrived");
            String s = message.toString();
    NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, CHANNEL_ID)
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.common_google_signin_btn_icon_dark)
            .setContentTitle(topic)
            .setContentText(s)
            .setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_DEFAULT);
    NotificationManagerCompat notificationManager = NotificationManagerCompat.from(this);
    notificationManager.notify(1, builder.build());


    somefun();
    }
```

`messageArrived()` does get executed when message is received because I get notifications.

Comment: Your function might be running from background thread, try to put **Runable** with with `runOnUiThread()` method to notify your adapter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Jeel suggested, messageArrived() was running on background thread. Running `notifyDataSetChanged()` on UI thread did the trick for me.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add method in the `adapter`

```
public fun setDatass(datasList: List<Datas>){
    this.datasList= datasList
    notifyDataSetChanged()
}
```

and call it in `activity` or in the `fragment`

```
    public void somefun(){
    Pump pump = new Pump("71xxxxxx", "East Motor", "OFF",R.drawable.motor);

    pumpList.add(pump);
    mAdapter.setDatas(pumpList);
}
```